# WatchKit 2.0 app's bundle ID person.bundle.Ropes.watchkitapp is not prefixed by the parent app's bundle ID followed by a '.'; expected prefix

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, watchos

When I use bundle id named like bellow. I have that error
[image: Unable to install "MyApp"]

(My app bundle: ilyabiryuk.bundle.Ropes)
But if I rename bundle like .watchkitapp It starts perfectly on simulator but give an error when I start it on my real watch(Series 3 42mm, watchOS 8.7.1)
How to fix that?
(IDE: Xcode 14 beta 6 (14A5294g))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the watch app info.plist, make sure the entry `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` is present and that its value is the bundle ID of the iOS app.

Comment: There is a one but: As I saw Xcode 14 doesn't create dependences between watch and iOS app, so you have to create them by your own

Comment: I just had this issue on Xcode 14, tried many things including adding ```WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier``` but it didn't work. Ended up doing something w/ the automatic provisioning and then it worked. (nothing new was added to the ```info.plist```)

Answer (score 3):

Bundle IDs should be as following:

- iPhone app bundle ID: com.myname.myapp
- Watch app bundle ID: .watchkitapp
- Watch extension bundle ID: .watchkitapp.watchkitextension

Note that Watch app and extension DOES NOT have parent application and start by a point (ie. relative bundle ID).

Comment: To confirm: BundleID for target WatchOS app should be ".watchkitapp" without com.appname? because when I do that I get Error: "The app identifier ".watchkitapp" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again."

Comment: @AskP is not true, if you set it like ".watchkitapp" you will not run app on real device.
we have to call it like "MyIOSApp.watchkitapp", if we develop ios and watch os together.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone tried all answers above. Here is what I got that finally worked:

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Add your iOS app bundle to `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier`

> Your simulator will scream that provisioning failed, ignored it.

3. Add your iOS app bundle to the Watch's `Build Identifier` field.

> Your simulator will scream that .watchkit 2.0 error and still will not
> work. Ignore it.

4. Save and close Xcode
5. Relaunch Xcode, and then build.
6. Worked for me with steps above.